# Hardness of the bin packing problem

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, np-hard, approximation

I have been reading up on the bin packing problem. In the bin packing problem, we are given $n$ items with sizes $a_1,a_2,\dots, a_n$ such that
$$
1 > a_1 \geq a_2 \geq \dots \geq a_n > 0
$$
The goal is to pack the items into bins such that each bin can hold any subset of items of total size at most 1, so as to minimize the number of bins used.

The problem that I am struggling with is that I read that unless $P = NP$, it is not possible for a polynomial-time algorithm to compute a solution to this problem with a number of bins less than $\frac{5}{4}\text{OPT}+\frac{1}{2}$ where OPT is the optimal number of bins for the problem instance. I do not see why this is the case. I already know that there exists a polynomial-time approximation algorithm returning a solution using at most $(1+\varepsilon)\text{OPT}+1$ bins for any $\varepsilon > 0$. Furthermore, I also know that we can use a reduction from the partition problem to show that unless $P = NP$, there does not exist a polynomial-time $\rho$-approximation algorithm for the bin packing problem for any $\rho < 3/2$. If someone could help me understand why there does not exist a polynomial-time approximation algorithm returning a solution that uses less than $\frac{5}{4}\text{OPT}+\frac{1}{2}$ bins unless $P=NP$, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: 1. I don't understand what is meant by "each bin can hold any subset of items of total size at most 1".  Can you please try to explain in different words?  That does not seem like an accurate statement of the bin packing problem, so I wonder if you're referring to some other problem.  2. Can you please provide a citation for each of the claims you made about approximations (5/4, $1+\epsilon$, 3/2)?

Comment: By "each bin can hold any subset of items of total size at most 1", I simply mean that the capacity of each bin is 1. For the $1+\varepsilon$ and $3/2$ approximation bounds, see chapter 3.3 of https://www.designofapproxalgs.com/book.pdf

Comment: @TheCollegeStudent I cannot find the lower bound claim of 5/4 OPT + 1/2 in this book, can you indicate the source of this claim as well?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to incorporate information into the question in a way that reads well for someone who encounters this for the first time, rather than putting clarifications and responses in the comments.